# Random number in a interval time VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if you can somehow create a time interval, like 1 second to display the random number. can this be done and how should I proceed?

```
Dim Rnd As New Random() 'No seed!
Dim lst As New List(Of Integer)
For i = 0 To 4
    lst.Add(Rnd.Next(0, 81))
Next
For Each i In lst
    TextBox1.Text &= i.ToString & vbCrLf
Next
```

Comment: You can use a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8), set it's `.Interval` To 1 second and `Start()` it. Put the code you want to execute in the event handler for the `YourTimerObject.Tick` handler

Comment: if you need help with events and eventhandling, see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/events/index) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-call-an-event-handler)

Comment: You can also loop as long as a Datetime.Now at start of method minus Datetime.Now inside the loop is >= 1s (actually -1, it's better to use Math.Abs). NOTE: this is making the application unresponsive for as long as it loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do this:

```
Observable.
    Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)).
    Take(5).
    Select(Function (x) Rnd.Next(0, 81).ToString()).
    ObserveOn(TextBox1).
    Subscribe(Sub (x) TextBox1.Text &= x & Microsoft.VisualBasic.vbCrLf)
```

The `Subscribe` method returns an `IDisposable` so if you want to stop the observable before if naturally finishes then just call `.Dispose()`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Timer to the Form in Design View. Set the Interval property to 1000.

Move `lst` declaration to the Form level and add a Form level `index` variable. The list can then be seen by more than one event procedure and the index will retain its value between calls to the `Tick` event.

After the list is filled start the timer. In the `Tick` event (occurs every 1000 milliseconds automatically) fill the text box one number at a time. Then increment the index so the next time the `Timer` ticks the next number will appear in the text box. When we reach the last index, stop the `Timer`.

```
Private lst As New List(Of Integer)
Private index As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Rnd As New Random() 'No seed!
    For i = 0 To 4
        lst.Add(Rnd.Next(0, 81))
    Next
    Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    TextBox1.Text &= lst(index).ToString & vbCrLf
    If index < lst.Count - 1 Then
        index += 1
    Else
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```